# All my derived tables have aliases! Why am I getting 'Error 1248: Every derived table must have it's own alias'?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Every time I run this query, I get:

> ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

As you can see, we have a parent query which left joins against a derived table created by a subquery.

This subquery in turn selects from a second derived table, and inner joins a third derived table.

All three derived table have proper aliases (`n1`, `n2` and `subquery`)

The subquery executes as expected when I execute it independently. The issue only occurs when I wrap it in the parent query.

Query:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(p.date_admitted, '%Y-%m') as month_admitted,
  diagnosis as diagnosis,
  education as education,
  COUNT(*) as total 
FROM patient_discharge_form d 
INNER JOIN survey_data sd ON sd.id = d.id 
LEFT JOIN submission s ON s.id = sd.submission_id 
LEFT JOIN patient p ON p.id = s.patient_id 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT n1.id,n1.diagnosis,n2.education
  FROM (
          SELECT id,'Gest Hyp' as diagnosis FROM patient_discharge_form WHERE gestational_hypertension=1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id,'Pre w/ Sev' FROM patient_discharge_form WHERE preeclampsia_non_severe=1
        ) n1 
  INNER JOIN (
          SELECT id,'Written' as education FROM patient_discharge_form WHERE education LIKE '%written%'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id,'Verbal' FROM patient_discharge_form WHERE education LIKE '%verbal%'
        ) n2 ON n1.id=n2.id
) subquery ON d.id = subquery.id 
WHERE (s.status = 'complete') 
GROUP BY month_admitted, diagnosis, education
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? Which version? What are the table structures?

Comment: Are you certain this query is the one returning the error? Can you run this query in the MySQL client, and do you get the error or not get the error? If the query is running in application code, are you certain you have deployed the code and are running the version of code you think you're running?

Comment: The query looks good, Are you sure this is the query that's producing the error?

Comment: This query is slightly edited to remove client information from the table name. Otherwise, running it as displayed here returns the error. I will confirm MySQL vs MariaDB tomorrow when I am at my desk. However, the answer below (which is downvoted) may actually be the root of the problem - that person has correctly identified that `education` and `diagnosis` are ambiguously declared in the parent query, and may be the root of the error. Will confirm tomorrow.

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.12

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I don't see a problem with the *table* aliases in the query.  I wonder if this is *exactly* the query you are running.

However, I do see a problem with the column aliases.  The `education` column in the `select` (and perhaps `diagnosis` as well) is ambiguous.  It could come from either `d` or `subquery` and perhaps other tables as well.

In general, you should qualify *all* column names in a query to avoid problems.

Comment: This is exactly the query I am running. However, you are correct about the ambiguity in the aducation and diagnosis columns. I wonder if that is the root of my issue, and the 'typical' resolution of the error returned is misleading. I will confirm on Monday when I get back to my workstation.